# Queries for developing and listing a Marketing cloud App on Appexchange

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, appexchange, app-development

I'm developing a marketing cloud application which is to be listed to Appexchange. What I'm able to achieve is that I get the JWT token and able to make authenticated API calls to the Marketing org.

The questions or problems which I have been mentioned below:-

- How can I test this process of validating the process as an app, since I have utilized the JWT and made authenticated calls to the marketing cloud account where I had created the installed package.
- Is there a way that I can test my package created in marketing cloud by installing it and testing that is my process/feature working as a package which will be present in the package.
- Also, if I build my Marketing cloud application on the force.com platform, can it be listed on the Salesforce app exchange under the Salesforce Marketing cloud products/apps.